# Why does an invalid date parses successfully as a real date?

Tags: java, date, formatting, simpledateformat

Can someone explain to me how to get the following method to return a value of `false` for the input shown?  It's returning `true`, which is something I don't expect.

```
isDateValid("19/06/2012 5:00, 21:00","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

I think this should return `false`, but apparently Java doesn't think so. The actual date string provided contains these extra characters at the end: `", 21:00"`.

```
public static boolean isDateValid(String date, String dateFormat) 
{
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            df.setLenient(false);
            Date newDate = df.parse(date);
            System.out.println("Date value after checking for validity: " + newDate);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parse` doesn't necessarily use the entire `String`. This is very clear in [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)), emphasis mine:

> `parse`
>
> `public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException`
>
> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**
> See the [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) method for more information on date parsing.

---

You can detect if there are extra characters at the end of the string by using [`parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)). If `pos` is not equal to the end of the String, then there were extra characters remaining at the end.

Here is a working program including test rig that will properly check this the way you intend. In this program, `pos.getIndex()` will be `0` if it can't parse at all, a number that is too small if there are extra characters at the end, and equal if it works the way you want

```
public class DateFormatTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // should be false
    System.out.println(isDateValid("19/06/2012 5:00, 21:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
    System.out.println(isDateValid("19/06/201", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
    
    System.out.println();
    
    // should be true
    System.out.println(isDateValid("19/06/2012 5:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
  }

  public static boolean isDateValid(String date, String dateFormat) {
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setLenient(false);
    df.parse(date, pos);

    return pos.getIndex() == date.length();
  }
}
```